# TLC5940 16 PWM Output Iref Resistor

Tags: power, avr

I have just picked up the TLC5940 chip from TI that provides 16 PWM outputs.

The data sheet is [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf).

As mentioned in the data sheet, the max current at each output can be set by connecting a corresponding external resistor at the Iref pin.

What I am not sure about is the wattage rating of the this resistor. Does it depend on the current being sunk by the chip (higher the current the beefier this resistor needs to be)?

Looking at the power dissipation equation in the datasheet, there's no dependence on this resistor mentioned but I would like to be sure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage of the \$I_{ref}\$ pin is nominally 1.24V (from page 7 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf)), so you can easily calculate the current for a given resistor.

The current through that resistor is *not* the current sunk by the chip, it is merely used as a reference to set the current drive of the output pins, where the current sunk is given as $$I_{OUT (IDEAL)} = 31.5 \frac{1.24V}{R_{IREF}}$$

As the resistor is therefore typically in the range of, say, 200Ω-10kΩ, the power dissipated is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current through the IREF reference resistor varies based on it's value, the data sheet does not give an I<sub>IREF</sub>. Instead, it gives the voltage that it will see, at a given test condition.

```
PARAMETER                          TEST CONDITIONS  MIN  TYP  MAX  UNIT
V(IREF)  Reference voltage output  R(IREF) = 640 Ω  1.20 1.24 1.28 V
```

At 640Ω, it will typically see 1.24 Volts. Simple Ohms law, `P = V^2 / R` gives us power in watts. `1.24^2 / 640` = `1.5376 / 640` **= 0.0024 Watts.** That's much less than a regular 1/4th (0.250) Watt resistor. So, any resistor is good.